# GNU make - enforcing target order

Tags: makefile

Could someone please tell me if there is a way to enforce sequential execution of specific Makefile targets. For example, I have a Makefile that builds Libraries and Executables. Now, Executables depend on Libraries, so they must be built after the Libraries are built and staged. This is what I currently have in a single Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all: all_lib all_bin

.PHONY: all_lib
all_lib: $(dep_lib)

.PHONY: all_bin
all_bin: $(dep_bin)
```

I have two targets `all_lib` and `all_bin`, one builds all libraries and the other builds all binary executables. When I pass `-j` to make to run parallel jobs, I get build failures, because all targets run in parallel and binaries can't find shared library objects and staged header files.

I tried changing it to this to try and force some dependency order:

```
.PHONY: all
all: all_bin

.PHONY: all_lib
all_lib: $(dep_lib)

.PHONY: all_bin
all_bin: all_lib $(dep_bin)
```

But for some reason all targets still run in parallel I still get the same build failures. Any ideas?

Comment: See [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-order_002donly-prerequisites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make is entirely built around the concept of dependencies.  You are simply not using it that way.

If an executable depends on a library, then you should list that library in the prerequisites list of the executable.  I can't give you a relevant example because you don't provide any details about the contents of `dep_lib` or `dep_bin` above, but for example:

```
exe1 : exe1.o liblib1.a liblib2.a
```

etc.  Now, `exe1` won't attempt to be linked until after the `liblib1.a` and `liblib2.a` targets have been created.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice, I got it now. Just realised, another way to solve this would be to run recursive make for each `all_lib` and then `all_bin` targets.

Comment: Well, there are lots of ways to solve it.  Some are more "correct" on a conceptual level.  Recursive make would not be considered a best-practice when writing makefiles that merely need to clarify a dependency relationship like this (although unlike some purists, I believe recursive make has its place and is a useful and powerful tool in _some_ situations).  But if it works, and you understand it, that's better than something that doesn't work or you don't understand even if it's not the most make-like method.